# 一部のデーターがDBに登録されない

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

sqlalchemyを利用してsqliteへデーターを追加したのですが、
一部のデーター（ここでは、password_hash）だけが、追加されず、nullとなってしまいます。
自分でも、見直しを行っておりますが、間違いが見つからない状況です。

間違い等ご指摘、アドバイスいただければと思います。

```py
# app.py

import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
 
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
 
    def __init__(self, email, username, password_hash):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"UserName: {self.username}"
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```py
# init_user.py

from app import db, User
 
db.create_all()
 
user1 = User("test_user1@test.com", "Test user1", "111")
user2 = User("test_user2@test.com", "Test user2", "222")
 
db.session.add_all([user1, user2])
db.session.commit()
 
print(user1.id)
print(user2.id)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

提示コードでは引数`password_hash`値が代入されていません。
以下のように修正するとよいでしょう。

```
    def __init__(self, email, username, password_hash):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = password_hash # ***
```

Comment: 有難うございます。代入していませんでした。。。